# Add new columns to existing table in a migration in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-5.5

I want to add some new columns in my existing table `users` in laravel.

I have already googling for that and following those search I have already created migration using the command `php artisan make:migration add_columns_to_users`.

**add_columns_to_users.php**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('city');
        $table->string('tribe');
        $table->string('country');
        $table->integer('student_id');
        $table->string('tribe_university_name');
        $table->string('student_program_of_study');
        $table->string('faculty');
        $table->string('level');
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->dropColumn('address');
        $table->dropColumn('city');
        $table->dropColumn('tribe');
        $table->dropColumn('country');
        $table->dropColumn('student_id');
        $table->dropColumn('tribe_university_name');
        $table->dropColumn('faculty');
        $table->dropColumn('level');
    });
}
```

After creation, I run this command `php artisan migrate`.

But got the same error:

> Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `password` varchar(255) not null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)

Full name of user table `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php` and the other name is `2019_04_11_074552_add_column_to_users.php`

How to solve this?

My main query is **How to add new columns in my existing table?**

Comment: Can you post the full file names of the initial user table migration and the new one

Comment: @thisiskelvin....  I have updated my post...please check

Comment: Whenever you want to add a new column into table best practice is to write a new migration, in this case you have to write migration add_column_to_users --table = users .
then add column name in migration and run php artisan migrate.

Comment: Make sure that your migration class name is `addColumnToUser`.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki...yes it is `AddColumnToUsers`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you check at the error trace:

> Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists

This means that the **users table** already exists so when you run your migrations it is trying to create a table that is already created in your database.

**Note:** Don't forget to backup your database first

Delete **users table** from the database also delete users entries from **migrations** table.

After, execute the migrate Artisan command:`php artisan migrate`

---

Now another your Question is: **How to add new columns in my existing table?**

You have to create a table using this command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

The output you got it like this: *Created Migration: 2019_04_12_070152_create_users_table*

Your Migration structure is something this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Now you want to **add new columns in your existing users table**

```
php artisan make:migration add_phone_number_to_users_table --table=users
```

use the `Schema::table()` method (as you're accessing an existing table, not creating a new one). And you can add a column like this:

```
public function up()
{
     Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->string('phonenumber')->after('name'); // use this for field after specific column.
     });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('phonenumber');
    });
}
```

After, you can run your migrations: `php artisan migrate`

Your new columns(`phonenumber`) are now added to your existing **users table**, which you can view in your database.

If you have still any doubt, see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArNb3xMY-Gc)

Answer (score 2):

You need do little modification in your artisan command

```
artisan make:migration add_columns_to_users_table
```

You then need to use the 
 Schema::table() method (as you're accessing an existing table, not creating a new one). And you can add a column like this

```
  public function up()
  {
     Schema::table('users', function($table) {
          $table->type('column');
      });
   }
```

add the rollback option:

```
 public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->dropColumn('column');
    });
 }
```

Then you can run your migrations:

```
 php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying current migration wont work, because it's entry in `migration` table is already there. So to make any changes in already existing table, you need to create new migration  script.

```
// remember `create` replaced by `table` here  

Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) { 
    // add whichever new columns you want to
});
```

Follow these steps,

1. `php artisan make:migrate modify_user_table`
2. open `modify_user_table` file in `database/migrations` directory
3. Add new columns as at top I wrote.
4. Now save the file after adding new columns into new migration file
5. cmd -> `php artisan migrate`

**EDIT**

1. If there is no user data then Open `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php` file and add `Schema::dropIfExists('users');` before `Schema::create('users'...` line.
2. If there is data then you can take a backup, again follow the above step 1.

Comment: This post doesn't fix the issue of the OP.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Can you elaborate on why? This is the process we follow, to add new columns in the already migrated table. And its full proof and already tested process.

Comment: Because the problem isn't in _the process we follow to add new columns_, he already followed the right process... So what's the point of telling him something he already did and we can see that from the Posted code.

Comment: Got you mate! I will see what can I do. Thanks :)

Comment: get the backup of database. empty your database. `php artisan migrate`. remove migration table from that old backup and run that backup sql.i.e. import. It is must work solution if nothing works.

Comment: @RahulMeshram...it's awefull solution :(...
Actually I don't want to do that...that's why all these tries

Comment: ***if nothing works*** that's why I mentioned. Still check if there are still any efforts or alternatives left to try. Do this at last. Because sometimes it's ***Bermuda Triangle*** :)

Answer (score 1):

Please do the  step 1.
`php artisan migrate:reset`
Step 2: Go to your database using PHPmyadmin (or similar) and delete all remaining tables

- including the migration table.

After all please do  Step 3 `php artisan migrate`

Comment: This is really awesome practice. Imagine Facebook one day decides to add new field, like `is_developer`, and um.. they have to reset all users. Clever.

Comment: i have a smarter and simplest solution... delete the db and run php artisan migrate.. hahahah @BenjaminBeganović

Comment: @BenjaminBeganović ofc just do `php artisan db:wipe` and then `php artisan migrate --seed` to add the new stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the `php artisan migrate` that will try to migrate both files when `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php` is already migrated, so IMO two possible solutions here :

1. Rollback the `users` table from the DB and rerun the migrate cmd.
2. Add the migration name inside the `migrations` table so the cmd will not try to run it for the second time.

Comment: What have you did until now? This is a simple issue that we may face in our daily work, you don't have to waste more time with it... Fix it and go on.

Answer (score 0):

You probably got the error because you tried to create another `Users` table, which is already exist on your database. That could be the reason why you find error `Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists`.

So, the solution is try to alter you existing `Users` table, instead to run another syntax to create and override `Users` table. By create another `alter class` inside your data migration folder. It used to be inside your `modules` folder on your Laravel Project (`../database/migrations/`).

- After you find the directory, create new alter class. For example, `alter_users_table.php`.
- So, if you would like to add another column (e.g.: `age` column, with type `int`, nullable) on your `Users` table, you could code like this on `alter_users_table.php`:

```
class AlterUsersAddAge extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('Users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->int('age')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('Users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('age');
        });
    }
}
```

- After that, try to run `php artisan migrate` on your terminal.
- Now you should see another new column `age` on your `Users` table.