# Not updating any column name in the table showing exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

`Student` table is created through this command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_students_table
```

This is successful.

When in the students migration file I add the code like that in the image.

Then I run the command

```
php artisan migrate
```

but I get an exception as shown in the screenshot.

I want to create a student table, and to update these columns:

1. id
2. name
3. email

but this is not updating. I tried a lot - I am a beginner, so I need help.

Exception:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55629491/5882307

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add new columns to existing table in a migration in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55629242/add-new-columns-to-existing-table-in-a-migration-in-laravel)